# Pandas, groupby and summing over specific months

Tags: python, pandas, sum

I have a DataFrame :

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 982 entries, 2009-10-30 00:00:00 to 2012-12-16 00:00:00
Data columns (total 4 columns):
rain        981  non-null values
temp_max    982  non-null values
temp_min    982  non-null values
temp        982  non-null values
dtypes: float64(4)
```

For summing per Year/Month  i use :

```
mdata = data.groupby([lambda x: x.year, lambda x: x.month]).agg([sum])
```

But i need Seasonal analysis (summer, winter etc), so how i can create the Sum of specific months like [1 ,2 ,3] of each year?

Ty

Comment: I would have thought you could map a seasons dictionary to your data and then group based on that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, one solution which  seems neat to me is to use a Seasons dictionary and then group the data using a function. Any function passed as a group key is called once per index value and the return values are used as the group names.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandas import DataFrame
import datetime
# Create a year's worth of data
base = datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(365)
Datelist = [base + datetime.timedelta(days = x) for x in range(365)]
DF = DataFrame(np.random.rand(365), index = Datelist)

# Create a Seasonal Dictionary that will map months to seasons
SeasonDict = {11: 'Winter', 12: 'Winter', 1: 'Winter', 2: 'Spring', 3: 'Spring', 4: 'Spring', 5: 'Summer', 6: 'Summer', 7: 'Summer', \
8: 'Autumn', 9: 'Autumn', 10: 'Autumn'}

# Write a function that will be used to group the data
def GroupFunc(x):
    return SeasonDict[x.month]

# Call the function with the groupby operation. 
Grouped = DF.groupby(GroupFunc)
Grouped.sum()
```

The function takes each index value and looks up the month in the Seasons Dictionary and returns the value corresponding to the month key. This value then becomes the group name.

Alternatively you can use the lambda as in your example (which is more efficient, but I thought the above would be easier to understand):

```
DF.groupby(lambda x: SeasonDict[x.month]).sum()
```

ADDITIONAL CODE AS PER COMMENTS
It seems to me like you would be better off slicing the data. So you could do the following

```
DF['Season'] = ""
for row in DF.index:
    DF.Season[row] = SeasonDict[row.month]
DFWinter = DF[DF.Season == 'Winter']
```

Now you have a new data frame with the winter data in, to play with as you desire.
The difference is that the groupby operations allow you to undertake the same operations on all the data, whereas it sounds like you wanted to investigate the properties of different parts of your data set in different ways. To do that its better to slice, in this case using Boolean slicing.

Comment: Woody Pride, ty for your answer. I am using `DF.groupby([lamdba x:x.year, lambda x: SeasonDict[x.month]]).agg(sum)`,  but how i can actually select only winter data to continue further analysis?

Comment: Yes, that looks good. So you you then have the data grouped by Year/Season. But you want only the winter data? Is that right? If so then you should not be grouping by year/Season. In fact you need not group at all, you can just slice the data. Or am I missing something? Do you in fact want to work with all the groups, or solely the winter data?

Comment: I trying to have a dynamic way of choosing data. For example, different plot of data.Winter.Sum per Year , and Data.Summer.Sum per Year will provide me useful information of my dataset.

Comment: It sounds to me like it would be better if you just created a Season variable, and then you can slice the data based on that. I'm not sure you need the groupby operations. I will update the answer now... pelase vote for the answer if you like it. Thanks

Comment: Your updated answer is that i was looking. It a pretty good solution for seasonal analysis. Ty

Comment: FWIW, `lambda`s are *not* more efficient in terms of time or space complexity, they compile to the same bytecode as an equivalent function. You could argue they are more efficient to type, but there's no non-aesthetic reason to use a `lambda` versus a function defined with `def`.

Comment: Good to know. Yes, sorry I use efficient in a very finger movement related way.