# How to sum over all values between 2 repeating values in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have pandas dataframe with Columns 'Date' and 'Skew(float no.)'. I want to average the values of the skew between every Tuesday and the store it in a list or dataframe. I tried using lambda as given in this question [Pandas, groupby and summing over specific months](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19615667/pandas-groupby-and-summing-over-specific-months)  I but it only helps to some over a particular week but i cannot go across week i.e from one tuesday to another. Can you give how to do the same?

Comment: Can you give some example data and the desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example with random data

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date' : pd.date_range('20130101', periods=100), 
                   'Skew': 10+pd.np.random.randn(100)})
min_date = df.Date.min()
start = min_date.dayofweek

if start < 1:
    min_date = min_date - pd.np.timedelta64(6+start, 'D')
elif start > 1:
    min_date = min_date - pd.np.timedelta64(start-1, 'D')

df.groupby((df.Date - min_date).astype('timedelta64[D]')//7).mean()
```

Input:

```
>>> df
         Date       Skew
0  2013-01-01  10.082080
1  2013-01-02  10.907402
2  2013-01-03   8.485768
3  2013-01-04   9.221740
4  2013-01-05  10.137910
5  2013-01-06   9.084963
6  2013-01-07   9.457736
7  2013-01-08  10.092777
```

Output:

```
           Skew
Date
0      9.625371
1      9.993275
2     10.041077
3      9.837709
4      9.901311
5      9.985390
6     10.123757
7      9.782892
8      9.889291
9      9.853204
10    10.190098
11    10.594125
12    10.012265
13     9.278008
14    10.530251
```

Logic: Find relative week from the first week's Tuesday and groupby and each groups (i.e week no's) mean.